# Push element in array which is the key of another object at specific position

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose model looking like that :

```
"question": {
    "_id": "1234",
    "title": "Hi",
    "content": "Hello",
    "viewed": 34425,
    "answers": [{
        "vote": 0,
        "date": "2015-12-21T13:03:14.334Z",
        "author": "john",
        "content": "hello",
        "comments": []
    }, {
        "vote": 0,
        "date": "2015-12-21T13:05:27.411Z",
        "author": "patrick",
        "content": "bonjour",
        "comments": []
    }]
}
```

I want to push a comment into `question.answers[1].comment` but I don't manage to do it with `findOneAndUpdate`.
Here is what i've attempted :

```
MySchema.findOneAndUpdate({_id: questionId}, 
    {$push: 
        {'answers.$.comments': {
              '$each': [comment], 
              '$position': 1}
        }
    }, function(err, doc) {...
```

but I get this error : `MongoError: exception: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: answers.$.comments`.

Comment: I've just edited the question, adding the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that to use the positional [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) update operator the array field must appear as part of the query document.

```
MySchema.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": questionId, "question.answers.author": "patrick" }, 
    { "$push": { "question.answers.$.comments": { "$each": [comment] } } }, 
    function(err, doc) {
        //Do something
    }
)
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-in-the-embedded-document-using-the-array-index):

> If you know the array index of the embedded document, you can specify the document using the embedded document’s position using the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation).

```
MySchema.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": questionId }, 
    { "$push": { "question.answers.1.comments": { "$each": [comment] } } }, 
    function(err, doc) {
        //Do something
    }
)
```