# how do i push a document on a nested mongodb

Tags: mongodb

if I want to add a review, with author,rating and reviewText to the first title, how do I do it.

```
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("58dd21c3cb77090b930b6063"),
        "bookAuthor": "wwww",
        "titles": [{
            "title": "this is title",
            "_id": ObjectId("58dd3f2701cc081056135dae"),
            "reviews": [],
            "favouredBy": [
                "bb, aa, cc"
            ]
        }, {
            "title": "this is the second tittle",
            "_id": ObjectId("58dd42a59f12f110d1756f08"),
            "reviews": [],
            "favouredBy": [
                "all"
            ]
        }],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

from with in the application this is what I tried but keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" error

```
    module.exports.reviewsCreate = function(req, res) {
        if (req.params.bookid) {
            Bok
                .findById(req.params.bookid)
                .select('titles')
                .exec(
                    function(err, book) {
                        if (err) {
                            sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
                        } else {
                            doAddReview(req, res, book);
                        }
                    }
                );
        } else {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {
                "message": "Not found, bookid required"
            });
        }

    };

    var doAddReview = function(req, res, book, author) {
        console.log(book);
        if (!book) {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 404, "bookid not found");
        } else {
            book.titles.reviews.push({
                author: author,
                rating: req.query.rating,
                reviewText: req.query.reviewText

            });
            book.save(function(err, book) {
                var thisReview;
                if (err) {
                    sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
                } else {
                    sendJSONresponse(res, 201, book);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push element in array which is the key of another object at specific position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665550/push-element-in-array-which-is-the-key-of-another-object-at-specific-position)

Comment: sorry for being vague i included the code i used.